# How does ternary operator work in the function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ternary-operator

Can you explain to me the return line in this algorithm?

The function is supposed to take a string and return it's Pig Latin version which is that it takes the first consonant or consonant cluster and puts it to the end of the string adding "ay" at the end.

If the string starts with a vowel it's supposed to just add "way" at the end.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  function check(obj) {
      return ['a','i','u','e','o'].indexOf(str.charAt(obj)) == -1 ? check(obj + 1) : obj;
  }

  return str.substr(check(0)).concat((check(0) === 0 ? 'w' : str.substr(0, check(0))) + 'ay');
}

// test here
translatePigLatin("consonant"); // should return "onsonantcay"
```

Comment: Not sure what you're really asking here? `return` just returns the value of the function?

Comment: @ProEvilz, how does the logic work in the return line of translatePigLatin function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats just hard to grasp because the names are horrible. `obj` is actually a number used to go to a position in the string, so it should rather be named `pos` or something. `check` doesnt check anything, it just traverses forward until the first vowel was found so it should be:

```
 const firstVowel = (pos = 0) => "aeiou".includes(str.charAt(pos)) ? pos : firstVowel(pos + 1);
```

Now the last line just takes the part from the first vowel (removes the consonants at the beginning):

```
 str.substr(/*from*/ firstVowel() /*till end*/)
```

If the first vowel is directly at the beginning:

```
 firstVowel() === 0
```

it just appends

```
 "way"
```

otherwise it takes those consonants at the beginning:

```
 str.substr(0, /*to*/ firstVowel())
```

and appends an "y".

Comment: Your function is technically different OP's. Use original code provided...

Comment: I never stated you did or did not know what you were doing so I'm unsure why you're clarifying whether you do or don't.. other than to be petty, perhaps?

Comment: @proEvilz exactly that. `your function is technically different OP's` because of ... ? Very vague claim without any helpful feedback or criticism `use original code provided` an imperative which is not helpful either.

Comment: I'm not sure how it isn't extremely obvious given you wrote your code? Does OP's have an arrow function? Does OP's use a string of `aeiou` or does it use an array? I'm surprised you had to ask how it's different. Use orignal code e.g. take OP's code, break it down and explain it. They didn't request for a new function to be create and subsequently for it to be explained

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code explains it with the comments.

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  function check(obj) {
      return ['a','i','u','e','o'].indexOf(str.charAt(obj)) == -1 ? check(obj + 1) : obj;
  }

  //return str.substr(check(0)).concat((check(0) === 0 ? 'w' : str.substr(0, check(0))) + 'ay');
  // The above is explained as equivalent to below:
  
  if(check(0) === 0){
    return str.substr(check(0)).concat('w'+'ay')
  }
  return str.substr(check(0)).concat(str.substr(0, check(0))+'ay')
}

// test here
console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant")); // should return "onsonantcay"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually helpful to break ternary statements down into if/else blocks in cases where you are unsure what they do.

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  function check(index) {
      // return ['a','i','u','e','o'].indexOf(str.charAt(obj)) == -1 ? check(obj + 1) : obj;
      // break down ternary into traditional if also changed obj to index to be more descriptive
      const vowels = ['a','i','u','e','o'];
      // if the character at the given index exists then check the next character
      if (vowels.indexOf(str.charAt(index)) === -1) {
        return check(index + 1)
      }
      // otherwide return index (vowel case)
      return index;
  }

  // return str.substr(check(0)).concat((check(0) === 0 ? 'w' : str.substr(0, check(0))) + 'ay');
  // set base translated word as the first letter in word that is not a vowel.
  const indexKey = check(0)
  // get string after index key
  let substringed = str.substr(indexKey)
  // get string from beginning until indexkey
  let appended = str.substr(0, indexKey);
  // if the index key is the first letter (word starts with vowel) use 'w'
  if (indexKey === 0) {
    appended = 'w';
  }
  // return string
  return `${substringed}${appended}ay`;
}

// test here
const singleConsonant = translatePigLatin("constant");
const doubleConsonant = translatePigLatin("chain");
const vowel = translatePigLatin("analyze")
console.log(singleConsonant, doubleConsonant, vowel);
```